# How can I enable Hot Module Replacement(HMR) in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, hot-module-replacement

Does the create-react-app come with built-in support for HMR? I have seen react app reloads on changes. But that's not HMR.
What webpack configuration I need to add to enable HMR.
I read online about setting `hot` option in `webpack-dev-serve` to `true`. I'm confused about HMR in react.

**After searching for a while I came across this**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'

// Opt-in to Webpack hot module replacement
if (module.hot) module.hot.accept()

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**Then it says to add `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` in `webpack.config.js`**
Do I need to manually add it or it comes pre-added.
Also I read that react uses `ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin`. I'm confused please help.

Answer (score 3):

First, we have to remember how HMR works:

> It allows all kinds of modules to be **updated** at runtime without the need for a *full* refresh.

Second, we have to remember how React works: It only **updates** the parts of the DOM that need to be updated. For instance, if you have a React app and you *add* a paragraph to it, a DOM node for the paragraph will be added and the page won't reload. If you change the contents of an existing paragraph, only the DOM node that represents the contents of the paragraph will be reloaded, because it needs to be re-written.

Third,

> Since webpack-dev-server v4.0.0, Hot Module Replacement is enabled by default.

Fourth,

Create React App uses webpack underneath the hood. You can see the entire configuration by ejecting it through the following cammand:

`npm run eject`

Putting it all together, Create React App does come with HMR enabled by default. You can confirm that by following the steps bellow:

1. Create and run an app by executing these commands:

```
    npx create-react-app my-app
    cd my-app
    npm start
```

2. After the app opens in your browser, select a piece of text, for instance, the word "reload". Then, go to your source code and change the background color of the application in the `App.js` file. You'll notice that the background color changes without a full refresh, since the text remains selected. Now, if you change the contents of the paragraph in your source code, you'll see that the selection disappears. This is React taking place an re-writing the DOM, only the small piece that needs to be updated. Furthermore, if select the text of the paragraph in your browser and go to your source code and change the contents of the link, you'll see that the content of the link is updated without clearing the selection, again, because React will only update the pieces of the DOM that need to be updated.

Comment: The video you linked to is from many many years ago and is deprecated.
It's also unconventional to link to videos from answers, as a Stackoverflow answer should be whole and provide all relevant information within it to answer the question

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll update the answer as soon as I can.